# Displaying video in Flex

Tags: apache-flex

I am new to FLEX and I am planning to display video on web page.My mxml code is below

```
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="horizontal">
     <mx:Array id="movieList">
        <mx:String>http://localhost/Flex/Butterfly.flv</mx:String>
     </mx:Array>
     <mx:VBox>
        <mx:List id="cntlMovie" dataProvider="{movieList}" width="300" />
        <mx:Button label="Pause" click="cntlDisp.pause();" />
        <mx:Button label="Play" click="cntlDisp.play();" />
     </mx:VBox>
    <mx:VideoDisplay id="cntlDisp" source="{cntlMovie.selectedItem.valueOf()}"
      width="400" height="300" />
</mx:Application>
```

I am running Apache2.2.11 server. 
When I run the above code, the browser just hangs(does not respond).
When the video url(http://localhost/Flex/Butterfly.flv) is directly accessed, it prompts to download the video file.

Could someone provide some help on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) and monitor the request (you might need to use your computer name instead of localhost). Is the request coming through to the server? What's the response status code?

Comment: Thanks.Now I can play the video.